# How does the output depend on the order of evaluation of arguments in this piece of code?

Tags: c, side-effects

While understanding side effects in programming, I came across this code:

```
    int add(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }

    int main()
    {
        int x = 5;
        int value = add(x, ++x); // is this 5 + 6, or 6 + 6?  It depends on what order your compiler evaluates the function arguments in



       printf("%d",value); 
    return 0;
}
```

I do not understand why the output here is order-dependent. I mean, if the first argument is evaluated first, then x is 5. Then ++x is evaluated, which changes x to  6. My doubt is that **x has been changed to 6**, this means that x in the first argument should also become 6. Therefore the function call effectively should be `add(6,6);`, which is the same if the second argument was evaluated first. Then why does the writer say that the result depends on the order of evaluation of the operands? Please explain. I am getting really confused while understanding side effects.

Comment: `warning: operation on ‘x’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]` Look at the rules regarding *sequence points*.

Comment: @Duncan  The function deals with copies of the values of its arguments. So if the left argument was evaluated first then the function will get the value 5 for its first parameter.

Comment: 'I came across this code' where?  A dumpster?  'My doubt is that x has been changed to 6,' DONT do this kind of stuff ever.  Apart from the UB, it's just bad code.  Bad.  Very bad.  If you can't understand what is going on, split it up until you can.  Stop writing bad code that you don't understand.

Comment: It's the same as so many 'real' order-of-operations  posts we get here. None of the professional/enthusiast programmers cares, because they've all made the order explicit by writing simple statements and/or adding maybe-redundant brackets.  If you're in doubt, bracket it out.

Comment: Sequence Point [**C11 Standard**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) `6.5.2.2 Function calls (10)` it is indeterminate.

Comment: C11 section 6.5 paragraph 2: **If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined. If there are multiple allowable orderings of the  subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is undefined if such an unsequenced side effect occurs in any of the orderings.**

Comment: 'understanding side effects' oh, that's easy.  Stop them happening at all by effective coding.  If an expression/statement cannot be understood immediately without looking up precedence tables and standards, it's bad code.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit any I/O is a *side effect*, so you must use them to accomplish anything. But it's good practice to limit side effects to a certain region of your system. (see also [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function))

Comment: You have posted the code without any context. You wrote "Then why does the writer say that the result depends on the order of evaluation of the operands?" Because it *does* depend on the order of evaluation of the arguments, but that order is *undefined*, and your logic is flawed: if the first argument is evaluated first, it is 5, not 6. The function is passed *values*, not *references*.

Answer (score 1):

Since functions receive their arguments by value, calling a function with expressions is equivalent to assigning those expressions to temporary variables, then calling the function with those variables. So

```
add(x, ++x);
```

If the arguments are evaluated left-to-right, it's equivalent to:

```
temp1 = x; // temp1 = 5, x = 5
temp2 = ++x; // temp2 = 6, x = 6
add(temp1, temp2); // add(5, 6)
```

If they're evaluated right-to-left, it's equivalent to:

```
temp2 = ++x; // temp2 = 6, x = 6
temp1 = x; // temp1 = 6, x = 6
add(temp1, temp2); // add(6, 6)
```

C doesn't specify the order that arguments are evaluated, and specifically states that code like this produces undefined behavior because of it.

Comment: Here is where I'm confused. I don't doubt the correctness of your answer, but is it *undefined*? -- or -- defined but *indeterminately sequenced*?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin See the quote from the standard by Ian Abbott in the comments.

Comment: Got it, `a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined.`

Comment: per the precedence of C operators table at: <http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm>, the parameters are evaluated left to right,

Comment: @user3629249 Associativity is not the same as evaluation order. `f1()-f2()-f3()` can call the functions from right to left, then subtract the results from left to right.

Comment: BTW, don't put `<>` around URLs in comments. The parser thinks the `>` at the end is part of the URL.

Comment: @Barmar,  What would be the right way to apply URLs, since the parser performs incorrectly when presented with <>?

Comment: You can just paste the URL directly, it's usually pretty good at parsing it. Or you can use markdown: `[text](URL)`. `text` will be the visible link, and it will link to URL.